# Devise, Rolify and Cancan to ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, cancan

I am developing an app using Devise, Rolify and CanCan. Can I shift it completely to be administered by ActiveAdmin. Is there any documentation for that?

Comment: This will help you to achieve your task... http://dan.doezema.com/2012/02/how-to-implement-a-single-user-model-with-rails-activeadmin-and-devise/

Comment: Furthermore, there is a [tutorial describing how to use Devise, CanCan and rolify together](https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Tutorial). I can imagine that you could combine both guides to setup your project.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a while since the question was asked... but as I found it while doing a google search, I think I can post an answer to help others.

So! There is a documentation to make ActiveAdmin use Cancan for its authentication and authorization system. Here is a [very simple how to add a CancanAdapter in ActiveAdmin](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html#using_the_cancan_adapter)

In fact they even explain how to create your own Authorization Adapter.

And yeah, Rolify does have [a good documentation on how to make it work with Devise + Cancan](https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Tutorial)

Thanks to those two documentations every Rails developer should be able to make all the pieces fit together. I'll be glad to help anyone in trouble by providing more information if needed.